# statistics problem

Tags: statistics

Five people own and operate the Victrola Coffee Shop in Seattle. Each person is married, and the number of years each has been married is given below.

5, 3, 7, 2, 12

Suppose a random sample of two of the owners is selected with replacement. Let D be a statistic defined to be the absolute value of the difference in the number of years each has been married. For example, if 2 and 7 were selected, the value of D would be |2 − 7| = | −5| = 5. Find the sampling distribution of D.

Comment: This is not a 'do my homework for free service'!

Comment: i literally have no clue what they are asking me to do

Comment: They are asking you to calculate all possible differences, and the probability of each one of them.

Comment: so as a permutation count

Comment: What???????????

Comment: so like create a table of sampling distributions, right?

Comment: Yes, and use it in order to write down the PDF (probability distribution function).

Comment: ok that makes sense thank you

Answer (score 0):

**Hints:**

There are $5^2 = 25$ equally likely possibilities for choosing two numbers. Find the absolute difference for each. From there you can find the sampling distribution.

I have done a brief simulation in R with a million samples as specified,
and tabled the resulting approximate distribution of $D.$ It should give
you a rough idea what to expect. It seems possible values of $D$ are
0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 7, 9, 10. What is the probability of each? (The 
simulation is accurate to only a few decimal places. Your probabilities
should be of the form $i/25.$)

```
m = 10^6;  d = numeric(m)
pop = c(5, 3, 7, 2, 12)
for (i in 1:m) {
    d[i] = abs(diff(sample(pop, 2, repl=T))) }  
table(d)/m
## d
##        0        1        2        3        4 
## 0.199989 0.079764 0.160214 0.080052 0.080129 
##        5        7        9       10 
## 0.159982 0.079991 0.080073 0.079806 
mean(d);  sd(d)
## 3.839428
## 3.219872
```

The histogram below shows the approximate sampling distribution of $D$.

[image]

Comment: You have some work to do. Good luck with it. (This is a little like finding the distribution of the _sum_ when two fair dice are rolled, except that has 36 possibilities.)

Comment: yes...Thank you again

Comment: `pop = c(5, 3, 7, 2, 12); table(abs(outer(pop, pop, "-")))/length(pop)^2` would give you the table without simulation